# pytest: skip addfinalizer if exception in fixture

Tags: exception, pytest, fixture

I have a function, that should do report, if test function success.

But, I don't want to do report, if there is an Exception inside test function.

I try to use pytest.fixture, pytest.yield_fixture, but all of them always call finalizers. How can I understand, that Exception had been raised in test function?

```
test.py StatisticClass: start
FStatisticClass: stop
finalizer
```

contest of test.py:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("statistic_maker")
def test_dummy():
    raise Exception()
```

content of conftest.py:

```
class StatisticClass():

    def __init__(self, req):
        self.req = req
        pass

    def start(self):
        print "StatisticClass: start"

    def stop(self):
        print "StatisticClass: stop"

    def if_not_exception(self):
        """
        I don't want to call this if Exception inside yield.
        Maybe, there is any info in request object?
        """
        print "finalizer" 


@pytest.yield_fixture(scope="function")
def statistic_maker(request):
    ds = StatisticClass(request)
    ds.start()
    request.addfinalizer(ds.if_not_exception) 
    yield
    ds.stop()
```

P.S. I can't use decorator because, I use fixture.

Comment: Maybe right way to use common python decorator?
It works fine :)

`@decorator_statistic()
def test_dummy():
    raise Exception()`

`def decorator_statistic():
    def real_decorator_statistic(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):

            ds = StatisticClass("")
            ds.start()
            try:
                ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
                ds.if_not_exception()
            except Exception, err:
                raise Exception(err)
            finally:
                ds.stop()
            return ret
        return wrapped
    return real_decorator_statistic`

Comment: I can't using decorator, cause I need fixtures in test function (